# Python Tkinter Removing a Frame on button click

Tags: python, tkinter, button, frame

I'm trying to make an application that has the functionality to add and remove frames based on a button click. For now, I'm trying to get it to remove the last frames added from the root and will add in the functionality to specify what frame to delete later.

When I create the frame, I add it to a list of objects like this:

```
def AddFrame(self):
    newFrame= customFrame(len(self.frameList))
    self.frameList.append(newFrame)
    newFrame.pack()
```

As I'm trying to delete it by reference, I'm using pop and pack_forget to both remove it from the list and removing it from the GUI. My basic function is:

```
def RemoveLastFrame(self):
    if(len(self.frameList)>0):
        self.frameList.pop().pack_forget()
```

I tried the pack_forget by testing it on a specified frame that I made in the init method. I'm not sure if this issue is coming from me trying to do this on a list of frame objects, or if it's due to the frame object's being a child of tk.Frame. Here is the child class in full:

```
    class customFrame(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, index):
            super(customFrame, self).__init__()
            self.index = index
            self.buttons= []
            self.addButton = tk.Button(command=self.AddButton,text='Add Button to Frame')
            self.addButton.pack()
    
        def AddButton(self):
            newButton = customButton(len(self.buttons))
            newButton.config(text=('Button '+str(newButton.index)))
            self.buttons.append(newButton)
            newButton.pack()
    
    
class customButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self,index):
        super(customButton, self).__init__()
        self.index = index
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. It was working, but it didn't unpack the children of the frame as well as I expected it to. Once I changed that, it works perfectly